# RingCentral - accessing call logs of ALL users

Tags: calllog, ringcentral

I would like to download the call logs of all my account's users. As I only have one user in my sandbox account, I cannot test it yet.

In production mode, if I call `/account/~/extension/~/call-log` while logged in as the admin of my account, would I get the full list directly?

Alternatively, I have read in a post that I could achieve what I want by calling `/account/~/extension` and then the url above for each extensions, but I wanted to know if there was a more straightforward way of doing it.

Have a great day!

Comment: In addition to John's comment, to access account level call-log , the user who is logged in should be a Super Admin role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two APIs to retrieve call logs for all users:

- account-level call log to retrieve all users at once
- extension-level call log for each user of interest

**Account Call Log API**

`/account/~/call-log`

The account call-log API can be used to retrieve call logs for all users in one API call. Access to this account-level API requires Super Admin privileges. This API is currently in beta and available by creating a support case from the developer portal or emailing RingCentral dev support at devsupport@ringcentral.com .

**Extension Call Log API**

`/account/~/extension/~/call-log`

If you were to extension call-log endpoint in an account with multiple users, you would only receive the CDRs for your authorized extension. To retrieve call logs for all users using the extension call-log API, you would need to retrieve all the extensionIds from the `/account/~/extension` endpoint and then call each user's extension endpoint using `/account/~/extension/{extensionId}/call-log`. This approach also lets you limit who you want to retrieve records for.